# How to add to an array using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am pretty new to angular and web development in general and I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with my code. Essentially I'm just trying to add to a table that uses ng-repeat by using $scope.arrayname.push. Let me know if I wasn't clear on something. Here are the relevant files:

My angular file:

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);
...
routerApp.controller('eventController', function($scope) {

$scope.events = [];  
$scope.addEvent = function () {

      $scope.events.push ({
        name: $scope.eventName,
        start: $scope.startDate,
        end: $scope.endDate,
        location: $scope.locationid
      });

      // Clear input fields after push
      $scope.eventName = "";
      $scope.startDate = "";
      $scope.endDate = "";
      $scope.locationid = "";
};

});
```

and here is my html file where the input goes:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h2>The Event Page </h2>
</div>
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6" ng-controller="eventController">
        <div ui-view="columnOne"></div>
        <input value="" type="text" placeholder="Name of Event" ng-model="eventName">
        <input value="" type="text" placeholder="Start Date" ng-model="startDate">
        <input value="" type="text" placeholder="End Date" ng-model="endDate">
        <input value="" type="text" placeholder="Location" ng-model="locationid">
        <button ng-click="addEvent()">Add to Event List</button>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div ui-view="columnTwo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the data should be outputed in a table here:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="event in events">
        <td>{{ event.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ event.start }}</td>
        <td>{{ event.end }}</td>
        <td>{{ event.location }}</td>
         <!---<td>{{ event.link }}</td>--->
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am using partial views with routerApp from angular. Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/FBoWuEQYhCwtTtNN9Wrk?p=preview

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The eventController is used in 2 different views and each gets it's own clean $scope when created. Use a service to share the same data across both instances of the controller.

Comment: I didn't even know about services, thanks for the advice! Looking into it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a few changes to get this to work. The main issue is that the scope isn't being preserved between your table view and the button press so even though the value is bound (you can console.log(events) and it will output correctly) it doesn't display.

First I named the controller ec and moved it up a level

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h2>The Event Page </h2>
</div>
<div class="row" ng-controller="eventController as ec">

  <div class="col-sm-6" >
    <div ui-view="columnOne"></div>
    <input value="" type="text" placeholder="Name of Event" ng-model="eventName">
    <input value="" type="text" placeholder="Start Date" ng-model="startDate">
    <input value="" type="text" placeholder="End Date" ng-model="endDate">
    <input value="" type="text" placeholder="Location" ng-model="locationid">
    <button ng-click="ec.addEvent()">Add to Event List</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div ui-view="columnTwo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I changed the controller to point to "this" instead of $scope

```
routerApp.controller('eventController', function($scope) {
      var ec = this;
      ec.events = [];
      ec.addEvent = function () {
          ec.events.push ({
            name: $scope.eventName,
            start: $scope.startDate,
            end: $scope.endDate,
            location: $scope.locationid
          });

          // Clear input fields after push
          $scope.eventName = "";
          $scope.startDate = "";
          $scope.endDate = "";
          $scope.locationid = "";
      };
});
```

And finally I changed the ng-repeat to use ec.events

```
<tr ng-repeat="event in ec.events">
```

There's probably a better way to do it with services or something like that to share the scope but that's all I could get to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Definitely going to look into services and see if I can make it work that way also.